# How to replace a complex term in an equation using a function?

Tags: notation, proof-writing

I have recently been working on a few models that look at mosquito predation. Now one of the peers wants me to add the complete equation of my model in the manuscript. I previously had the equation broken down in several parts but the reviewer was not happy with that. So I decided to add the full equations, here is an example:

$$N_{e}=N{}_{0}-\frac{W\left(\frac{a}{1+c(P-1)+abcN_{0}(P-1)}bN_{0}\exp\left(-\frac{a}{1+c(P-1)+abcN_{0}(P-1)}(PT-bN_{0})\right)\right)}{\frac{a}{1+c(P-1)+abcN_{0}(P-1)}b}$$

The editor of the journal now told me to break it down again. This are his exact words: "*...there is one complex term that occurs three times. This term could be replaced by a function name, e.g. F(x, y, z, …), and then F(x, y, z, ..) defined in the following line.*"

I'm not really sure how to write this because I am not very good with mathematical notations, symbols and all that. Is the editor basically asking my to do the following?:

$$N_{e}=N{}_{0}-\frac{W(F(x,y,z)bN_{0}\exp(-(F(x,y,z)(PT-bN_{0})))}{(F(x,y,z)b}$$

and then:
$$F(x,y,z)=\frac{a}{1+c(P-1)+abcN_{0}(P-1)}$$

If this is what he is asking I don't see how this differs with my first version in which I had the following:
$$N_{e}=N{}_{0}-\frac{W\alpha bN_{0}\exp(-(\alpha(PT-bN_{0})))}{\alpha b}$$
combined with:
$$\alpha=\frac{a}{1+c(P-1)+abcN_{0}(P-1)}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say something like this:

For notational convenience, let
$$F:=\frac{a}{1+c(P-1)+abcN_{0}(P-1)}.$$
Then our model is
$$N_{e}=N{}_{0}-\frac{W(F\,bN_{0}\exp(-(F\,(PT-bN_{0})))}{F\,b}.$$

Here, the $:=$ means "is equal to be definition".

It's not clear to me if variables on the right-hand side of $F$ are indeed independent variables or parameters. If variables, I'd say $$F(a,b,c,P,N_0):=$$ instead of $$F:=$$ but they feel like parameters to me. And if they are indeed parameters, I'd probably choose a different letter than $F$ to represent that quantity.

You're right, this isn't any different than what you had using $\alpha$ unless the point of this is to treat $\alpha$ as a *function* of those variables on the right-hand side of the defining expression for $\alpha$ (or $F$).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. a,b and c are parameters that should be estimated while P and N0 are measured variables. Does that mean that it should look like this: $F(P,N_{0}):=$ ?

Comment: In that case, sometimes we write $F(P,N_0):=\cdots$ and say "where $a,b,c$ are parameters." Other times, depending on what we are trying to communicate, we may even write $F(P,N_0;a,b,c):=\cdots$. I lean toward the former rather than the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You have same things written three times : it s a function F

the function depends on a,b,c,$N_{0}$, and P so your function can be written $F(a,b,c,N_{0},P)$

$N_{e}=N{}_{0}-\frac{W(F(a,b,c,N_{0},P)bN_{0}exp(-F(a,b,c,N_{0},P)(PT-bN_{0}))}{F(a,b,c,N_{0},P)b}$

or

$N_{e}=N{}_{0}-\frac{W(FbN_{0}exp(-F(PT-bN_{0}))}{Fb}$ where $F=\frac{a}{1+c(P-1)+abcN_{0}(P-1)}$

Note you have on extra ')' at the end

Comment: Thanks for your help. Seems like the editor just wants what I had in the first place but he doesn't know it yet.